# Widget stops receiving data after app crashes or user kills the app?

Tags: android

I have an app which plays music in a `Service`. There is also a Widget to control the music player. Everything works fine.

Now after the user closes the app or if it crashes or if I use `System.exit();` or `getActivity().finish();` to close it there are some problems. Everything seems to work fine, but somehow the widget doesn't receive broadcasts anymore even though another `Activity` still receives them.

The widget is still able to send broadcasts, it is only unable to receive them.

Could somebody please help me out?

Code from my widget:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    ma = (GlobalSongList)context.getApplicationContext();

    context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(broadcastCoverReceiver, new IntentFilter(Music_service.BROADCAST_COVER));

    context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(broadcastPlayPause, new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_PLAYPAUSE));
    context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(checkagain, new IntentFilter("xyz"));
    context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(intentshuttingdown, new IntentFilter("shutdown"));

    RemoteViews controlButtons = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);

    Intent playIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_PLAYPAUSE);
    PendingIntent playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, playIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    controlButtons.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bPlay, playPendingIntent);


    Intent previousIntent = new Intent(why);
    PendingIntent previousPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, previousIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    controlButtons.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bprev, previousPendingIntent);

    if(ma.NP_List.size()>0) {
        controlButtons.setTextViewText(R.id.song, ma.NP_List.get(ma.position).song);
        controlButtons.setTextViewText(R.id.artist, ma.NP_List.get(ma.position).getArtist());

        Intent open_activityIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_open_activity);
        PendingIntent openactivityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, open_activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        controlButtons.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.parent, openactivityPendingIntent);

        if(ma.boolMusicPlaying1 == true) {
            controlButtons.setImageViewResource(R.id.bPlay, R.drawable.pause2);
        } else {
            controlButtons.setImageViewResource(R.id.bPlay, R.drawable.play);
        }
    } else if(ma.NP_List.size() == 0) {
        controlButtons.setTextViewText(R.id.song, "");
        controlButtons.setTextViewText(R.id.artist,  "");
    }

    Intent nextIntent     = new Intent(BROADCAST_SWAP);
    nextIntent.putExtra("nextprev", 1);

    PendingIntent nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, nextIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    controlButtons.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bNext, nextPendingIntent);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, controlButtons);
}

public BroadcastReceiver broadcastCoverReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent serviceIntent) {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), MyWidget.class);
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
        if (appWidgetIds != null && appWidgetIds.length > 0) {
            onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Well post some relevant code. Nobody is going to be able to help you just from that description, we need to see what you did too. But `System.exit()` might already be the problem. **NEVER** use `System.exit()`. The OS controls when an app is killed, trying to interfere with that will only cause problems.

Comment: well i have written "or" it is not the only scenario ......

Comment: please tell me what code should I post ?

Comment: All the relevant code, the parts that are not working as expected and everything else you think might be important.

Comment: code for service,code for widget or code for the activity which starts the service ?

Comment: the thing is there is so much code that i would only confuse people if i post it here

Comment: Well you are supposed to show us the relevant code, not all of it. You say your widget is not working? Then show us the code of your widget. Or show us the code where you send broadcasts to the widget.

Comment: updated my question with code in it..

Comment: **1)** Your code is formatted terribly, I already took care of that this time, but next time format it properly before posting here. **2)** `ma.c=context;` don't understand what you are trying to do here, makes absolutely no sense. **3)** You are registering the `BroadcastReceiver` again and again in `onUpdate()`, why don't you declare them in your manifest? Now you just register them every time your widget is updated and you never unregister them. You really should just declare them in your manifest. Or is there a specific reason why you are doing it programmatically?

Comment: And why do you need all those `BroadcastReceivers` in the first place? You are supposed to update your widget with `updateAppWidget()` of the `AppWidgetManager`.

Comment: ma.c=context; yes i was  trying to do something,it isn't required any more ...sorry for that,will remove that....
i like doing it pragmatically...that's how i have done it every time

Comment: Why? It's a lot more work and you cannot just do that. If you register a `BroadcastReceiver` programmatically you also have to unregister it again. Not unregistering a `BroadcastReceiver` is bad. And that you register them again and again so many times is also very bad. Just add them to your manifest and you don't have to worry about registering and unregistering them at all, the OS will take care of that. But more importantly: Why do you need them at all. You are supposed to update your widget with `updateAppWidget()` and not with `BroadcastReceivers`.

Comment: okay this(by using broadcastreceivers) is how i am registering my notification and also many views in various activities and fragments so i thought it would be easier to use broadcastreceivers instead of updateAppwidget() also i would like to know if i register the broadcast in the manifest,will i have to create a new class/file for broadcasts ?currently i am using the same class to declare the broadcasts

Comment: even in this tutorial ,the guy uses broadcasts 

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html

Comment: can you suggest any tutorial for updateappwidget ?

Comment: Why don't you follow the [**official guide**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)? And in the tutorial you are linking to he is not using `BroadcastReceivers` like you do.

Answer (score 1):

You should use android app widget and not use broadcasts since it is the most conventional way of doing it....which is also mentioned in the docs

Answer (score 0):

You should `bind` and `unbind` background service on `onResume` and `onPause` respectively in Activity.

Visit [Android Activity and Service relationship - after Pause, after Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6657166/1583653) to get to know relationship between Service and Activity